# Is the Minecraft folder structure the same on all platforms?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm making a resource pack editor for Minecraft in python. It needs to access the versions folder of Minecraft, but I need to know if, once inside the Minecraft folder, the structure is the same on all platforms, ex. the versions folder is always `versions/`, the resource packs folder is always `resourcepacks/`, or if it's different on every platform.

I know the location of the Minecraft folder is different on every platform, but what I want to know is if the location of the folders *inside* the Minecraft folder change.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, the contents of the folder will be the same

Long answer: Yes, however the location differs. If you're using python, you can use the `sys.platform()` function to get that data. Typically, the default locations are:

- **Windows**: `%appdata%/.minecraft`
- **MacOS (darwin)**: `$HOME/Library/Application Support/minecraft`
- **Linux**: `$HOME/.minecraft`

It might also be useful to allow the user to choose a custom `.minecraft` path if they're using a custom launcher.

Edit: According to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1857/9071915), you should try to use `platform.system()` for a more consistent output

Comment: Thanks! But can python open files in Windows if I just put in, for example, `%appdata%/.minecraft/versions/1.17.1/1.17.1.jar` as the path? Or do I need to pass it through some function like `os.path.expanduser()` or `os.path.absolutepath()`?

Comment: You should be able to use either `os.getenv('APPDATA')` or `os.path.expandvars(r'%appdata%\.minecraft\path\to\foo')`